# Finite dimensional $\text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$-module and its eigenspace

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$-module ($\text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$: Lie algebra of traceless complex matrices) and, for $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$ $$V[\mu]=\{v\in V|h.v=\mu\cdot v\}$$ the subspace of V consisting of eigenvectors for the action of $h=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ with eigenvalue $\mu$.

Why do we have $V[\mu]=\{0\}$ for $\mu\notin\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: May we assume that $h=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$? Is it acceptable to use the fact that $V$ is a direct sum of irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$-modules?

Comment: Yes, we can assume both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expresse as a direct sum of irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$-modules. On the other hand, if $W$ is such a module and if its dimension is $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the the eigenvalues of the action of $h$ on $W$ are $n-1$, $n-3$, $n-5$, ..., $-n+1$. Therefore, all eigenvalues of the action of $h$ on $V$ are integers.

Comment: How do you get these eigenvalues?

Comment: It is a standard result about representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. You will find a proof <a href="http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Seitz-McLeese.pdf">here</a>, for instance.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Welcome to math.se!  Just a tip on formatting: you can include links using the format `[text](link)`.  Your last sentence would then be, "You will find a proof [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Seitz-McLeese.pdf), for instance."

Comment: @Quasicoherent Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @user114179 Please use the link at the comment posted by Quasicoherent. That one does work.

Comment: Where exactly can I find the proof there? It seems that this needs a lot of theory I am not familiar with.

Comment: See the last 6 pages.